# Preserving whitespaces in a string as a command line argument

Tags: bash, scripting, whitespace

I'm facing a small problem here, I want to pass a string containing whitespaces , to another program such that the whole string is treated as a command line argument.

In short I want to execute a command of the following structure through a bash shell script:
command_name -a arg1 -b arg2 -c "arg with whitespaces here"

But no matter how I try, the whitespaces are not preserved in the string, and is tokenized by default. A solution please,

edit: This is the main part of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#-------- BLACKRAY CONFIG ---------------#
# Make sure the current user is in the sudoers list
# Running all instances with sudo

BLACKRAY_BIN_PATH='/opt/blackray/bin' 
BLACKRAY_LOADER_DEF_PATH='/home/crozzfire'
BLACKRAY_LOADER_DEF_NAME='load.xml'
BLACKRAY_CSV_PATH='/home/crozzfire'
BLACKRAY_END_POINT='default -p 8890'
OUT_FILE='/tmp/out.log'

echo "The current binary path is $BLACKRAY_BIN_PATH"


# Starting the blackray 0.9.0 server
sudo "$BLACKRAY_BIN_PATH/blackray_start"

# Starting the blackray loader utility
BLACKRAY_INDEX_CMD="$BLACKRAY_BIN_PATH/blackray_loader -c $BLACKRAY_LOADER_DEF_PATH/$BLACKRAY_LOADER_DEF_NAME -d $BLACKRAY_CSV_PATH -e "\"$BLACKRAY_END_POINT\"""

sudo time $BLACKRAY_INDEX_CMD -a $OUT_FILE

#--------- END BLACKRAY CONFIG ---------#
```

Comment: Sorry, but you've provided too little information.

What shell do you use (bash, ksh, csh, ...)? Can you tell what command you try to execute? If it is a standard UNIX utility, can you say its version?

Comment: bash script. Ok here's what I'm trying to do:

....
BLACKRAY_END_POINT="default -p 8890"
....
CMD="$BLACKRAY_BIN_PATH/blackray_loader -c $BLACKRAY_LOADER_DEF_PATH/$BLACKRAY_LOADER_DEF_NAME -d $BLACKRAY_CSV_PATH -e \"$BLACKRAY_END_POINT\""
...

Now I want to execute the above command such that $BLACKRAY_END_POINT is treated as a single string and not get tokenized. $BLACKRAY_END_POINT is a string containing spaces and bash splits it into different words. I want to preserve the spaces and pass the whole string as a single argument.

Comment: Unknown, meet backslash-double-quote (\"). Backslash-double-quote, meet unknown.

Answer (score 5):

You're running into this problem because you store the command in a variable, then expand it later; unless there's a good reason to do this, *don't*:

```
sudo time $BLACKRAY_BIN_PATH/blackray_loader -c $BLACKRAY_LOADER_DEF_PATH/$BLACKRAY_LOADER_DEF_NAME -d $BLACKRAY_CSV_PATH -e "$BLACKRAY_END_POINT" -a $OUT_FILE
```

If you really do need to store the command and use it later, there are several options; the bash-hackers.org wiki has a [good page on the subject](http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/mirroring/bashfaq/050). It looks to me like the most useful one here is to put the command in an array rather than a simple variable:

```
BLACKRAY_INDEX_CMD=($BLACKRAY_BIN_PATH/blackray_loader -c $BLACKRAY_LOADER_DEF_PATH/$BLACKRAY_LOADER_DEF_NAME -d $BLACKRAY_CSV_PATH -e "$BLACKRAY_END_POINT")

sudo time "${BLACKRAY_INDEX_CMD[@]}" -a $OUT_FILE
```

This avoids the whole confusion between spaces-separating-words and spaces-within-words because words aren't separated by spaces -- they're in separate elements of the array.  Expanding the array in double-quotes with the `[@]` suffix preserves that structure.

(BTW, another option would be to use escaped quotes rather like you're doing, then run the command with `eval`.  Don't do this; it's a good way to introduce weird parsing bugs.)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**:

Try:

```
BLACKRAY_END_POINT="'default -p 8890'"
```

or

```
BLACKRAY_END_POINT='"default -p 8890"'
```

or

```
BLACKRAY_END_POINT="default\ -p\ 8890"
```

or

```
BLACKRAY_END_POINT='default\ -p\ 8890'
```

and

```
BLACKRAY_INDEX_CMD="$BLACKRAY_BIN_PATH/blackray_loader -c $BLACKRAY_LOADER_DEF_PATH/$BLACKRAY_LOADER_DEF_NAME -d $BLACKRAY_CSV_PATH -e $BLACKRAY_END_POINT"
```

**Original answer**:

Is blackray_loader a shell script?

Here is a demonstration that you have to deal with this issue both when specifying the parameter and when handling it:

A text file called "test.txt" (include the line numbers):

```
1 two words
2 two        words
3 two
4 words
```

A script called "spacetest":

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "No quotes in script"
echo $1
grep $1 test.txt
echo

echo "With quotes in script"
echo "$1"
grep "$1" test.txt
echo
```

Running it with `./spacetest "two--------words"` (replace the hyphens with spaces):

```
No quotes in script
two words
grep: words: No such file or directory
test.txt:1 two words
test.txt:2 two        words
test.txt:3 two

With quotes in script
two        words
2 two        words
```

You can see that in the "No quotes" section it tried to do `grep two words test.txt` which interpreted "words" as a filename in addition to "test.txt". Also, the `echo` dropped the extra spaces.

When the parameter is quoted, as in the second section, `grep` saw it as one argument (including the extra spaces) and handled it correctly. And `echo` preserved the extra spaces.

I used the extra spaces, by the way, merely to aid in the demonstration.

Comment: Agreed. But in my case, I'm not passing any args to my bash script, instead I'm hardcoding an argument(with spaces) which needs to be passed to a command. This command (blackray_loader) is called withing my bash script. I just need to preserve the argument's whitespaces and pass it as one whole string.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm demonstrating. In the script above, `grep` is a stand-in for your `blackray_loader`. Your command will need to properly handle the parameters. However see the edit for another thing to try.

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion:

```
# iterate through the passed arguments, save them to new properly quoted ARGS string
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
   ARGS="$ARGS '$1'"
   shift
done

# invoke the command with properly quoted arguments
my_command $ARGS
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all -- the shell parses quotes before it expands variables, so if there are quotes in the variable's values they don't get treated as quotes, just regular characters. Basically, it's too late for them to have the intended effect. What actually happens is that they get passed to the command as part of the argument, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

probably you need to surround the argument by double quotes (e.g. "${6}").

Following OP comment it should be "$BLACKRAY_END_POINT"

Comment: Tried. But it still takes just "default" and not the whole string :(

Comment: Replace -e \"$BLACKRAY_END_POINT\"" to "\"$BLACKRAY_END_POINT\"". You need "" to escape spaces in your script and additional \"\" to escape spaces when the command is executed

Comment: still no luck, it takes--> "default  as the arg now (extra open quotes). for running I am using: sudo time $CMD -a $OUT_FILE  . If I replace $CMD as "$CMD" , it gives me a no such file or directory error.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my example of restarting a script via **exec su USER** or **exec su - USER**.  It accommodates:

- being called from a relative path or current working directory
- spaces in script name and arguments
- single and double-quotes in arguments, without crazy escapes like: \\"

---

```
#
# This script should always be run-as a specific user
#
user=jimbob
if [ $(whoami) != "$user" ]; then
  exec su -c "'$(readlink -f "$0")' $(printf " %q" "$@")" - $user
  exit $?
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

A post on other blog saved me for this whitespaces problem: http://logbuffer.wordpress.com/2010/09/23/bash-scripting-preserve-whitespaces-in-variables/

By default, whitespaces are trimed:

```
bash> VAR1="abc        def    gh ijk"
bash> echo $VAR1
abc def gh ijk
bash>
```

"The cause of this behaviour is the internal shell variable **$IFS (Internal Field Separator)**, that defaults to whitespace, tab and newline.
To preserve all contiguous whitespaces **you have to set the IFS to something different**"

With **IFS** bypass:

```
bash> IFS='%'
bash> echo $VAR1
abc        def    gh ijk
bash>unset IFS
bash>
```

It works wonderfully for my command case:

```
su - user1 -c 'test -r "'${filepath}'"; ....'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Stop spreading retarded hacks, please. You're clearly showing that you don't understand the importance of quotes. _By default, whitespaces are trimed_: WRONG. Without quotes, you're going under word splitting and filename expansions. Cure this with quotes: `VAR1="abc        def    gh ijk"; echo "$VAR1"`. Now it works. Also, how would you explain what happens in the case of a wildcard: `VAR1='*'; echo $VAR1` vs `VAR1='*'; echo "$VAR1"`? Even with your `IFS` thing, you'll get the same horrible result: `IFS=%; VAR1='*'; echo $VAR1`. Just use more quotes. Period.

Comment: Can you explain me why filepath is trimed in this case : 'test -r "'${filepath}'" ' ?

Comment: You have to understand how quotes work. There are no nestings for quotes. I'll take your full command: `su - user1 -c 'test -r "'${filepath}'";'`. If `filepath` contains spaces, e.g., `filepath='a b'`, then when you do `su - user1 -c 'test -r "'${filepath}'";'`, bash will expand to the following words: `su`, `-`, `user1`, `-c`, `test -r "a`, `b";`. Not what you want. With `IFS=%` it _seems_ that it works, but it'll fail if `filepath` contains wildcards or the symbol `%` or the symbol `"` (or other globs).

Comment: In Bash there's the `%q` format modifier of `printf` that can help with your case: `printf -v filepath_escaped '%q' "$filepath"; su - user1 -c "test -r $filepath_escaped"`.